# How to save tree harmed by urine?

Tags: trees, fertilizer

Is it possible to save trees that are harmed by dog urine?

I have some young trees which died some time ago, and at first I didn’t understand why that happened. But it happened very suddenly. The trunk began to get black and the leaves became dry very fast.

Now I have a few trees again affected by these symptoms.

Is it possible to stop the dying of the young trees? Is there a counter elixir that will eliminate the saline solution, acids and highly concentrated urea (chloride)?

I have also heard that urine is a fertilizer, but apparently not for young trees and not if the urine is overdosed.

Will it help to water the affected trees extensively?

Comment: what kind of trees, what kind of soil, area of the world that you live in please

Comment: One dog, several trees? Unlikely (though not impossible) to be dog urine killing them off - more info, like how many trees, what were they, how big were they when planted, photos if possible, soil preparation prior to planting, aftercare you've carried out, how long between planting and dying... added to previous request for extra info...

Comment: I agree, erik!  Can't see dog urine killing trees.  It IS fertilizer and yes, one can overdo fertilizer easily.  But dog urine/cat urine/human urine is mostly water.  Will burn lawns/grass easily if the grass has been fertilized correctly.  Then you see brown spots.  Have you seen grass that hasn't been fertilized correctly and is peed on?  Bright green spots.  We really need a picture of your trees, including pictures of the base of your trees.  Pull back the mulch/soil until you see the top of the root ball.  Take picture...

Comment: Female dogs pee can burn lawns and leave patches, so anything is possible?  but I've never heard this one before...

Answer (score 4):

I would think that watering extensively should help to wash the excess nitrogen out (which is probably what is causing the problem). It does appear to be a water soluble form, after all. In fact, [this site that talks about urban legends about dog urine](http://www.ext.colostate.edu/mg/gardennotes/553.html) says that is the one and only true solution (to flush it out with water).

However, if the problem is that your plants are getting burned by nitrogen, rather than that the ground is just too 'salty', as they say, it might be good to add things that will help the nitrogen to be less problematic (such as balancing the other nutrients in proportion with the existing nitrogen. If the nitrogen is way too high, this may not be the best idea, though. If the dog is just going to keep urinating on it, I'd go with water all the way, though.

Anyway, when I talk about balancing nutrients, I mean, if your nitrogen is a whole lot higher than your potassium, your plants are more likely to get burned. Extra potassium can help to prevent this. Calcium levels may also play a role with the toxicity of nitrogen.

I'm not sure about dog urine, but human urine has an NPK value of about 11-1-2. That means it's about 11% nitrogen, 1% phosphorus and 2% potassium. Using it as fertilizer, I've heard you should use 1 part urine to 10 parts water, or so (but really, you shouldn't be using it at all if you couldn't use lots of nitrogen). A dog urinating on your tree is probably a lot like pouring way too much nitrogen on it. Adding extra water should definitely help, although I don't guarantee anything.

I would personally wash it out with water, and then add extra potassium (without adding any other nutrients, except maybe a little calcium and phosphorus, if you want—don't add any more nitrogen). You don't need to make the potassium equal the nitrogen to save the tree, though. You just need enough. I'm not sure how much is enough (but outdoors, it should be a fair amount less than the amount of nitrogen).

Really wet ground might make the remaining nitrogen more available to the tree, however, but hopefully more would wash out than would stay, and the extra potassium should help to soften the blow.